# standard Copy/Paste does not respond to a long press

Tags: android

I had this problem, did the usual SO research, and did not find a solution that
worked so I am offering up this one.

I came upon this error after I had wrapped a working `TextView` in a `ScrollView`. Some time later I tried the long press and discovered that it was no longer working. Fortunately I had been making daily backups. I found the two backups between which the anomaly occurred, did some StackOverflow research and got it fixed as follows ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textview.setTextIsSelectable` enables standard Copy/Paste in response to a
long press. However, if that TextView is wrapped in a ScrollView and if
`setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()` is called on the TextView, then the standard Copy/Paste will not respond to the long press.  Apparently you do not need the `setMovementMethod()` if the textview is wrapped in a ScrollView; furthermore, using it creates this difficult to find error.

Hope this helps :)